# drag & drop (and choose file) uploading

Tags: javascript, php, html, file-upload, drag-and-drop

How can I combine these two projects like this(no-dropzone.js):

[image: img]

I want only image file uploading (pnp, jpg etc.)

Project 1:

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>File upload</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" name="file">
            <input type="submit" value="upload">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**upload.php**

```
<?php
if(isset($_FILES['file'])) {
    $file = $_FILES['file'];

    // File properties
    $file_name = $file['name'];
    $file_tmp = $file['tmp_name'];
    $file_size = $file['size'];
    $file_error = $file['error'];

    // Work out the file extension
    $file_ext = explode('.', $file_name);
    $file_ext = strtolower(end($file_ext));

    $allowed = array('txt', 'jpg');

    if(in_array($file_ext, $allowed)) {
        if($file_error === 0) {
            if($file_size <= 2097152) {

                $file_name_new = uniqid('', true) . '.' . $file_ext;
                $file_destination = 'uploads/' . $file_name_new;

                if(move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $file_destination)) {
                    echo $file_destination;
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

**with**

Project 2

[image: img2]

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Drag & Drop Uploading</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/global.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="uploads"></div>
    <div class="dropzone" id="dropzone">Drop files here to upload</div>

    <script>
        (function() {
            var dropzone = document.getElementById('dropzone');

            var displayUploads = function(data) {
                var uploads = document.getElementById('uploads'),
                    anchor,
                    x;

                    for(x = 0; x < data.length; x = x + 1) {
                        anchor = document.createElement('a');
                        anchor.href = data[x].file;
                        anchor.innerText = data[x].name;

                        uploads.appendChild(anchor);
                    }
            };

            var upload = function(files) {
                var formData = new FormData(),
                    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(),
                    x;

                for(x = 0; x < files.length; x = x + 1) {
                    formData.append('file[]', files[x]);
                }

                xhr.onload = function() {
                    var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

                    displayUploads(data);
                }

                xhr.open('post', 'upload.php');
                xhr.send(formData);
            };

            dropzone.ondrop = function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                this.className = 'dropzone';
                upload(e.dataTransfer.files);
            };

            dropzone.ondragover = function() {
                this.className = 'dropzone dragover'
                return false;
            };

            dropzone.ondragleave = function() {
                this.className = 'dropzone';
                return false;
            };

        }());
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**upload.php**

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');

$uploaded = array();

if(!empty($_FILES['file']['name'][0])) {

    foreach($_FILES['file']['name'] as $position => $name) {
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$position], 'uploads/' . $name)) {
            $uploaded[] = array(
                    'name' => $name,
                    'file' => 'uploads/' . $name
                );
        }
    }
}

echo json_encode($uploaded);
?>
```

Comment: You could start by trying something and come back if you run into some _specific_ issue.